# Why is the number of phonon modes in a solid restricted to a finite value?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, waves, phonons

Kittel's [*Thermal Physics*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716710889) (Amazon link) makes the statement:

> There is no limit to the number of possible electromagnetic modes in a cavity, but the number of elastic modes in a finite solid is bounded. If the solid consists of three degrees of $N$ atoms, each with 3 degrees of freedom, the total number of modes is $3N$.

Why is the number of phonon modes bounded, when the number of photon modes is not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While a cavity can have modes of arbitrarily high frequency, a phonon can't have a wavelength smaller than the separation between atoms in the solid (well, it could, but it'd be degenerate with phonons of smaller frequency because the [discrete Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) is periodic). Hence, there is a maximum possible wavenumber.

A physical (or sometimes artificially introduced mathematical) limit on the upper frequency is some times called an "ultraviolet regulator". In the case of the crystal, the lattice spacing is a natural ultraviolet regulator.

Comment: What makes you say that?